# ARM syscall as c++ template

Tags: c++, templates, arm, inline-assembly, system-calls

I need to call some syscalls in my newlib stubs and the current implementation uses C macros which got unreadable and awful looking over time. (And I hate macros...)
However, my implementation with C++ templates does only work for one parameter:

```
template <int nr, typename RETTYPE, typename PARAM1> 
    inline RETTYPE syscall(PARAM1 p1)
{
  register PARAM1 r0 asm("r0") = p1;
  asm volatile("svc %[nr]\n"
    : "=r" (r0)
    : [nr] "i" (nr), "r" (r0)
    : "memory", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r12", "lr");
  return (RETTYPE) r0;
}
```

Now I can call e.g. malloc using

```
void *ptr = syscall<SYS_MALLOC, void*>(0x1000);
```

to allocate 0x1000 bytes.

My implementation for four parameters:

```
template <int nr, typename RETTYPE, typename PARAM1, typename PARAM2, typename PARAM3, typename PARAM4> 
    inline RETTYPE syscall(PARAM1 p1, PARAM2 p2, PARAM3 p3, PARAM4 p4)
{
  register PARAM1 r0 asm("r0") = p1;
  register PARAM2 r1 asm("r1") = p2;
  register PARAM3 r2 asm("r2") = p3;
  register PARAM4 r3 asm("r3") = p4;

  asm volatile("svc %[nr]\n"
    : "=r" (r0)
    : [nr] "i" (nr), "r" (r0), "r" (r1), "r" (r2), "r" (r3)
    : "memory", "r12", "lr");

  return (RETTYPE) r0;
}
```

doesn't work, the content of the registers at the "swi" instruction is arbitrary.
Somehow GCC doesn't respect the "register" variables anymore.
Example: I set a breakpoint at the svc instruction and execute

```
syscall<FWRITE, int>(ptr, 1, len, f)
```

But somehow r0 is set to 1 and r1 to ptr...
I also tried compiling without optimizations, just the order of the registers changed a bit, but it's still the wrong order. I know I could do "mov r0, %[param1]" etc. but that would prevent optimizations and therefore result in slower code.

Is it a bug in GCC (4.8.2) or did I overlooking something?

Comment: That looks all very clumsy :-/ ... I'd avoid `asm` in c++ code for any  efforts!!

Comment: Also note that the `register` keyword is deprecated for already a while now ...

Comment: Believe me, I would if I could ;-)

Comment: you may get what you want by setting same clobbers in second example, but it is not clear what you are trying to do just by reading the code.

Comment: It's ndless/TI-Nspire/Nucleus RTOS.
Could you explain why it should work if I add the parameters as clobbers? I already tried that and it didn't work. I'll try it again, though.

Comment: `inline` a syscall to *make it faster*? I see what you want to do, but it is much better just to define the actual functions once (emit them) and call to the address for `fwrite()`, etc.  Because #1, the `swi/svc/syscall` is **slow** to begin with.  #2 it will be smaller code if you use it more than once.  #3 Even if this *bug* is fixed, the compiler will have to generate horrid code (just like a function call sight).  The *syscall* arguments are like an ABI function call, so it is not intelligent to try and inline them.

Comment: A syscall is only used ~twice in the whole newlib stub collection.
The code generated isn't horrid at all, for my malloc example it generates
`mov r0, #0x1000
svc #8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [bug 33661](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33661), which is rather old. I encountered it myself several years ago.

It was fixed in 2021, 6 years after this question and answer were originally written.

Comment: Not every day that I click a random SO link and wind up reading about a compiler bug in support for inline assembly... Hats off to you sir.

Comment: Great :-(
The workaround with inlining a global non-template function in the template works. It's ugly, but works.