# Correctly passing arguments to supervisor calls with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, cortex-m

I'm using the following code to generate supervisor calls:

```
#define SVC(code) __asm__ volatile ("svc %0" : : "I" (code))

void svc_rgb(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue) {
    SVC(7);
}

int main() {
    svc_rgb(0, 255, 0);
    wait();
    svc_rgb(0, 255, 255);
}
```

for which I then have an SVC handler that takes care of implementing the functionality taking into account the passed arguments. However, that code produces the following disassembly:

```
0000a108 <main>:
    a108:       b510            push    {r4, lr}
    a10a:       df07            svc     7
    a10c:       f7ff ffec       bl      a0e8 <wait>
    a110:       df07            svc     7
    a112:       e7fe            b.n     a112 <main+0xa>
```

which ignores the rgb arguments passed to the `svc_rgb` function. Initially I thought that GCC was optimizing out the apparently unused parameters, so I added a `__attribute__((optimize("-O0")))` to the `svc_rgb` function. That yields the following dissassembly:

```
0000a0e8 <svc_rgb>:
    a0e8:       b590            push    {r4, r7, lr}
    a0ea:       b083            sub     sp, #12
    a0ec:       af00            add     r7, sp, #0
    a0ee:       0004            movs    r4, r0
    a0f0:       0008            movs    r0, r1
    a0f2:       0011            movs    r1, r2
    a0f4:       1dfb            adds    r3, r7, #7
    a0f6:       1c22            adds    r2, r4, #0
    a0f8:       701a            strb    r2, [r3, #0]
    a0fa:       1dbb            adds    r3, r7, #6
    a0fc:       1c02            adds    r2, r0, #0
    a0fe:       701a            strb    r2, [r3, #0]
    a100:       1d7b            adds    r3, r7, #5
    a102:       1c0a            adds    r2, r1, #0
    a104:       701a            strb    r2, [r3, #0]
    a106:       df07            svc     7
    a108:       46c0            nop                     ; (mov r8, r8)
    a10a:       46bd            mov     sp, r7
    a10c:       b003            add     sp, #12
    a10e:       bd90            pop     {r4, r7, pc}
```

which is not what I expect, since it makes it so that the first call to `svc_rgb` is such that the registers `r0`, `r1` and `r2` contain the values `255`, `0`, `0`, respectively, just before the `svc` instruction, passing the wrong values to the SVC handler.

How can I let GCC know that I'm going to use the parameters of `svc_rgb` as the arguments to my supervisor call?

Comment: Of course it optimizes away unused values.  You didn't use any input operands to tell the compiler that they're inputs to the asm statement.  Use `register int r0 asm("r0")` and so on to make `"r"` constraints pick the regs you want.

Comment: [ARM syscall as c++ template](//stackoverflow.com/q/22618412) shows how to ask for inputs to an ARM asm statement in registers.

Comment: You can also fix this by marking each function that uses `SVC` as `noinline`, although it's a fragile fix.  The correct way to fix this is to do what Peter Cordes said or to make `SVC` a function written entirely in assembly that is not to be inlined.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. This issue can be fixed using the template at [ARM syscall as c++ template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22618412).